# multivariable chain rule arguments

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Say there is some function $f(a,b,c)$ where $a = y +\alpha n$, $b = y' +\alpha n'$, $c =x$ where y and n are functions of x. If I want to differentiate $f$ with respect to $\alpha$, meaning $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}$, using the chain rule I get:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial a} \cdot   \frac{\partial a}{\partial \alpha} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial b} \cdot   \frac{\partial b}{\partial \alpha} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial c} \cdot   \frac{\partial c}{\partial \alpha} $$

The problem is that in  my textbook they made $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$ into $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}$ into $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$. How is that mathematically justified? Is that because $\frac{\partial a}{\partial y} = 1 $?

Comment: What is $y, y^{'}$ - in $a,b$ definitions - functions?

Comment: I'm sorry,  I will edit. They are fucntions dependent upon the variable x.

Comment: By the way, notice that in this way of writing the chain rule, two different functions are both called $f$. This is a common abuse of notation, but I think it causes some confusion.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Any other change? Differentiation of $f$ still with respect to $x$? What is $\alpha,n^{'}$ ? In such situation we wait dangerous from all sides.

Comment: $\alpha$ is a number. $n$ is a function of x. Prime signifies differentiation with respect to x if that wasn't clear here.